# Awesome or aweful - נורא

Tags: commentaries, language, deuteronomy

Looking at verses such as Devarim (Deuteronomy) 7:21 and 10:17 those seem to talk about a awe-inspiring and awesome G-d. Yet the word נורא also means aweful or terrible or dreadful.

So how should I define the word נורא in these verses? How can such a negative word be something positive when it comes to describing G-ds character?

Comment: Only means awful in modern Hebrew.

Comment: The word aweful originally meant causing awe, not as in modern English *extremely bad*. Thus the translation of נורא is not (as referring to Hashem) a pejorative.

Comment: awe-inspiring..

Answer (score 1):

The term awful (aweful is a misspelling) is actually used in both senses only in modern day English. Originally it was restricted to the meaning *filling with awe* which is the meaning for נורא

Thus, it is not a negative or pejorative meaning.

[For example](https://wikidiff.com/awful/aweful)

> Oppressing with fear or horror; appalling, terrible.
>
> Inspiring awe; filling with profound reverence or respect; profoundly
>   impressive.
>   *, I.56:
>
> God ought not to be commixed in our actions, but with awful reverence,
>     and an attention full of honour and respect.
>
> - 1819 , Lord Byron, Don Juan , II.143:
>
>   And then she stopped, and stood as if in awe / (For sleep is awful ).
>
> Struck or filled with awe. (obsolete) Terror-stricken. Worshipful;
>   reverential; law-abiding. Exceedingly great; usually applied
>   intensively.
>
> an awful bonnet
>
> I have learnt an awful amount today.
>
> Very bad.
>
> My socks smell awful .